# Resources for studying quantum metrology

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, metrology

I want to learn about quantum metrology topics like von-Neumann hamiltonian, ABL rule etc., typical case studies of interpretation of measurement, quantum contextuality etc., discussion on what is observer, what is a measurement apparatus etc.

What are some recent good review papers/books on these topics?
I know of two books, one is by von Neumann while other is Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods by Asher Peres. But both of these are pre 1990s, and in past 20yrs, due to advancement in mesoscopic and nanoscale technologies, a lot of experiments have actually been done that have advanced our understanding and want to know about a resource that takes into account the conclusions from these recent advancements on quantum metrology

Comment: ([Polino et al. 2020](https://avs.scitation.org/doi/10.1116/5.0007577)) is a recent one. You can also find references to other reviews there, see in particular references 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, and 17

Comment: another recent one is Barbieri's, see https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/abstract/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.010202